# Django Rendering HTML in a template give bytes

Tags: django, django-templates

In my django application, I am manually rendering a page and giving it to a template to include :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    page = render(self.request, test_absolute_path, context, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    soup.dosomestuff()
    page.content = str(soup.decode()).replace('\n','')
    context['subtests'].append(page)
    return context
```

Then including the rendered HTML into a template using the `safe` tag :

```
 {{ page.content | safe }}
```

I do have my tags included but the text appears like a bytearray and the encoding isn't right for some reason :

```
b'
My text Cat\xc3\xa9gorisation S\xc3\xa9quqsdazeences R\xc3\xa9ponses associ\xc3\xa9es Fluidit\xc3\xa9
```

Notice that I also had to replace all `\n` with nothing in the code.

EDIT :

I noticed that encoding the soup in ascii at least prints all the characters, I still can't get rid of the `\n` or `b` though :

```
page.content = soup.encode('ascii')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `page.content` always returns byte array. One option is to call decode in template tag.

```
{{ page.content.decode | safe }}
```

Another one is to use different name like below.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    page = render(self.request, 'viewbase/sub_page.html', context,
            content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    soup.dosomestuff()
    page.new_content = soup.decode()
    context['subtests'].append(page)
    return context
```

With that, the template has below tag.

```
{{ page.new_content | safe }}
```

Or directly put content instead of page in context in case you don't need anything else from the page.

```
    context['subtests'].append(soup)

{{ soup | safe }}
```